# Is there a code only version of "Size Classes"?

Tags: ios, class, size, autolayout

I'm writing my iOS 8 constraints in code instead of IB for oh-so-many-reasons.  I do not see a way to write constraints that are activated only in certain "size classes", as you can do in IB.

I suppose I could watch for a change in screen aspect ratios and then resetting the constraints, but is there a more documented way?

Thanks!
Henry

Answer (score 1):

Check out `UITraitCollection` and `UITraitEnvironment`.

`UIViewController` conforms to `UITraitEnvironment` which means you can get hold of it's `UITraitCollection` and also react when that changes via `traitCollectionDidChange:`

`UITraitCollection` contains horizontal and vertical sizeClass info along with displayScale and userInterfaceIdiom.